# Need javascript/ solution to send a mail stored in my database(filled by users in contact form)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a contact form which contain attributes like first name, last name, phone number etc. That information stores in my database. my requirement is either after  the information stored in database clicking submit in contact form or directly the information filled by user has to reach my mail. I need javascript for that. please help friends....I'm not good in javascript.

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAR-fxVU8rhScgFN6V5hDFr8DKAZI7KM5k",
    authDomain: "healthbharat-fa468.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "healthbharat-fa468",
    storageBucket: "healthbharat-fa468.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1058506343655",
    appId: "1:1058506343655:web:5915e61a8697670a818e42"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  //referencing the collection

let contactInfo = firebase.database().ref("information");

//listen for submit
document.querySelector(".form_container2").addEventListener("submit",submitForm);


function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //fetching the input values
    let fname = document.querySelector(".fname").value;
    let lname = document.querySelector(".lname").value;
    let email = document.querySelector(".mail").value;
    let number = document.querySelector(".phoneno").value;
    let country = document.querySelector(".country").value;
    let message = document.querySelector(".subject").value;

    //console.log(fname, lname, email, number, country, message);

    saveInformation(fname, lname, email, number, country, message);

    document.querySelector(".form_container2").reset();

    sendEmail(fname, lname, email, number, country, message);
}

//save the information to firebase

function saveInformation(fname, lname, email, number, country, message) {
    let newinformation = contactInfo.push();

    newinformation.set({
        fname: fname,
        lname: lname,
        email: email,
        number: number,
        country: country,
        message: message,
    });

    retrieveInformation();
}

//retrieve information
function retrieveInformation(){
    let ref = firebase.database().ref("information");
    ref.on("value", gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
    let infor = data.val();
    let keys = Object.keys(infor);

    for(let i = 0;i < keys.length; i++){
        let infdata = keys[i];
        let fname = infor[infdata].fname;
        let lname = infor[infdata].lname;
        let email = infor[infdata].email;
        let number = infor[infdata].number;
        let country = infor[infdata].country;
        let message = infor[infdata].message;

        console.log(fname, lname, email, number, country, message);
    }
}

//Sending email
function sendEmail(fname, lname, email, number, country, message) {
    Email.send({
       Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
       Username: 'Healthbharat',
       Password: "Healthybharat",
       To: 'avinash9490251214@gmail.com',
       From: 'healthybharatinfo@gmail.com',
       Subject: `${fname} has raised a complaint`,
       Body: `Name  ${fname} <br> Email  ${email} <br> Message  ${message}`,
    }).then( message => alert("mail sent successfully"));
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; are you asking how to send an email in JavaScript? If so, then in what context? From the browser? From an app?

Comment: I  have a website. In that I have a contact page. so when user enters data in contact page that information has to reach my mail. I need a possible way for that....?

Comment: Sure, depends entirely on your webpage. SO probably isn't the best place to start looking, though; your first step should be your ISP.

Comment: yep, what to do in ISP. ? seriously I don't have any idea about these. please push me to a solution

Comment: @I'm_not_a_genius You can use [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com) to send emails using cloud functions.